# Screensaver suppression on video playback

Tags: video, screensaver, lock-screen, idle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I stop the screensaver from turning on when I watching online videos?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144621/how-do-i-stop-the-screensaver-from-turning-on-when-i-watching-online-videos)

I migrated from Ubuntu 10.10 to Xubuntu 11.10 (clean install). Previously when I played video via fullscreen mplayer the screen lock didn't activate. Now I get screen lock after a couple of minutes whether the machine is just idle or playing.

Is there some option I have to switch to get this working?

Settings for screensaver:

- mode: blank screen only
- blank after 10 min
- cycle after 10 min
- lock after 10 min (+ enabled)
- advanced options checked: "fade to black when blanking", "grab desktop images"