# Screen goes dark while watching video

Tags: screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screensaver suppression on video playback](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79977/screensaver-suppression-on-video-playback)

My screen goes dark when I'm watching something online. To be more specific, the screensaver is on and the screen goes dark when I'm watching "The Daily Show" on their website. This does not happen when videos are being played in smplayer.

Of-course, when that happens I have to move the mouse and enter the password again.