# How to stop screensavers when playing a video?

Tags: video, lubuntu, screensaver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screensaver suppression on video playback](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79977/screensaver-suppression-on-video-playback)

I'm on Lubuntu and am using the default video player to play videos, but if I leave the mouse unmoved for too long the screensaver cuts in while I'm watching the video.  How do I go about disabling the screensaver only while a video is playing?  Ideally I'd like this to be done automatically, rather than something I need to manually do.  If this isn't an option in the default video player but is in others, I'm willing to switch my utility of choice.

Further info:

Turns out that caffeine doesn't actually seem to work on Lubuntu. The screensaver still comes on, even though I've configured Caffeine as such and its context menu indicates that the screensaver should be disabled (by showing the first option as "Enable Screensaver").