# How do I prevent screensaver to come up when watching full-window videos?

Tags: video, screensaver, video-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Screensaver suppression on video playback](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79977/screensaver-suppression-on-video-playback)

I can't prevent the screensaver from coming up when watching videos in full screen mode. Is there any way to fix this?